# Can’t submit form with hidden required field Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have set a required field hidden using jQuery. Whenever the user tries to submit the form it gives an error that says "There was a problem with your submission. Please review the fields below." but when I review the fields, no error is displayed. I am using the hidden required field for a condition statement which says if the number of shirts is not equal to the number of participants show the hidden required field, if they are equal hide the required field, which will allow the user to continue submitting the form successfully.

```js
$('#input_1_36_1,#input_1_18').change(function() {
  var participants = $('#input_1_36_1');
  var shirts = $('#input_1_18');
  var error = $('#field_1_45');
  if (Number(participants.val()) === Number(shirts.val())) {
    error.hide();
    //$('#field_1_48').hide(); //fake shirts
    $('#field_1_18').show(); //shirts
    $('#field_1_48').prop("class", "gf_invisible");
  } else {
    error.show();
    error.css('color', 'red');
    $('#field_1_48').show(); //fake shirts
    $('#field_1_18').hide(); //shirts
    // $('#input_1_48').prop("class", "gf_hidden");
    //$('#input_1_48').prop("readonly", true);
    //  $('#field_1_48').prop("class","gf_invisible");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
html here!
```

Comment: Please add the HTML perhaps in a snippet? so we can best assist you here.

Comment: `$('#field_1_48').prop("class", "gf_invisible");` is not really the right way to add a class to an element when you have jQuery in play.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a field using JS doesn't change its required status. You need a custom validation in PHP. Something like this:

```
// Ignore value of field 48 and set it valid if values of fields 36.1 and 18 are equal.
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_1_48', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $participants = rgpost( 'input_36.1' );
    $shirts = rgpost( 'input_18' );
    if ( $participants === $shirts ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = true;
        $result['message']  = '';
    }

    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Another cleaner option is using `gform_pre_validation`:

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation', 'my_conditional_requirement' );
function my_conditional_requirement( $form ) {
    $participants = rgpost( 'input_36.1' );
    $shirts = rgpost( 'input_18' );
    if ( $participants !== $shirts ) {
        return $form;
    }

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->id == 48 ) {
            $field->isRequired = false;
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I am comparing two number fields, its looks like gravity forms does not support it.